# Dynamic built in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to generate "datasets" as per the length of of object, if it consists of 3 items, then my "datasets" should create 3 items. In below example, r.d.BarData.length = 2, so I will have two list in "datasets". The items in BarData may vary, accordingly it should create "datasets"

```
//r.d.BarData.length = 2
//Then it should generate 
 datasets: [
    {
        label: "My First dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
        data: r.d.BarData[0].split(",")
    },
    {
        label: "My Second dataset",
        fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
        strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.8)",
        highlightFill: "rgba(151,187,205,0.75)",
        highlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
        data: r.d.BarData[1].split(",")
    }
]
```

Comment: why not `datasets = r.d.BarData` ?

Comment: r.d.BarData contains data like  ["11,22,44,43,56", "22,23,45,55,32"]

Comment: What exactly are you asking? It's not clear. Where are the `label` and `rgba()` colour values coming from, for example?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, may be I am not clear, trying again :)
 r.d.BarData may contain 2/3/5/8/n items, accoringly "datasets"  should contain 2/3/5/8/n items

Comment: I get that part, but what data should be placed in to `datasets`? We can see the properties of the object you've defined, but where to the values come from?

Comment: No need to change values for label, fillColor, strokeColor, highlightFill, highlightStroke. They can remain same, just need to change data:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you can use a loop to generate your datasets

```
 datasets = []
  $.each(r.d.BarData, function(i, d){
    datasets.push({
      label: "My First dataset",
      fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.8)",
      highlightFill: "rgba(220,220,220,0.75)",
      highlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
      data: d.split(",")
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks. It works as expected